# Give a user the permission to access files in a directory

Tags: files, permissions, solaris, nfs, acl

I have mounted a volume from NAS storage to my Solaris 10 machine using NFS. I want to give read/write permission for a user to the directories and subdirectories and files. I have tried

```
setfacl  -m user:biptip:rwx,mask:rwx NIADOCS/*
setfacl -R -m d:u:biptip:rw,u:biptip:rwX NIADOCS
```

but I am not able give the permission.

Comment: Can you describe what happens.  Do the commands generate errors, do they work but the user is still not able to access files, etc.  Also, can you show the command used to mount the NFS filesystem, and the resulting mount details.

Answer (score 1):

try to mount the filesystem you are trying to set acls on with acl options.

something like this in fstab:

```
/dev/rootvg/filesystem /filesystem                ext4    defaults,acl        1 2
```